# Best practices for using MVVM with Provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mvvm, flutter-provider

I have a Flutter app that uses Provider package together with MVVM pattern.
I'm always trying to make the viewModel responsible only for the functionality related to specific View but there is one use case I wasn't sure how I should approach.

I have an IntroView that does some initial download of data from DB and some checking mechanisms are happening there. One of the checks I perform is if user already answered the test that day (if they did, the bool is stored in SharedPreferences). Once user perform that action, first item on the bottomNavigationBar get's disabled until tomorrow when user can again perform the test.

The thing is that when user removes the app from running apps and start it again, I have a function that should retrieve the bool from SharedPreferences and if it's value is "true", it should call the function to disable the first item on the bottomNavigationBar.

The thing is that as I'm trying to make every ViewModel responsible for handling business logic only for the specific view I have the function to disable the first item on bottomNavigationBar placed in my ViewModel where logic for bottomNavigationBar sits.

So I'm calling the function that's in the "BottomNavBarViewModel" in my "IntroViewModel" and I wanted to know how to properly set the connection between them when I'm using Provider package.

I can always instantiate a new instance of "BottomNavBarViewModel()" but that would create a new instance which is not ideal if I want to maintain a single consistent state through the app.

So my question is: is there a best practice on how to call function that's in other viewModel when using a Provider package to manage single consistent state through the app?

Any guidance will be appreciated and sorry for long post!

Comment: I prefer riverpod over provider, and the architecture laid out in https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-app-architecture-riverpod-introduction/